# Seperate login for custom user and django admin in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm currently working on a django project and I have a custom user model in my django app. Custom user authentication is working perfectly, but the issue I'm facing is whenever I'm logging into admin account in the django admin site, it logs out the previous user(let say, user2) and admin being logged in.

How Can I separate their login, so that admin site logins don't interfere with my website login?

Here is my code attached:

**Custom User model and its manager:**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager


class CustomerManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, username, name, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address to register')

        if not username:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an username address to register')

        if not name:
            raise ValueError('Users must enter their name to register')

        user = self.model(
            email = self.normalize_email(email),
            username = username,
            name=name,
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using = self._db)
        return user


    def create_superuser(self, email, username, name, password=None):
        user = self.create_user(
            email = self.normalize_email(email),
            username = username,
            name=name,
            password=password,
        )

        user.is_admin = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user



class Customer(AbstractBaseUser):
    # user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    email           = models.EmailField(max_length=254, null=True, unique=True)
    username        = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True)
    name            = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    phone           = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True)
    address         = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
    date_joined     = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_login      = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    is_admin        = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active       = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff        = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser    = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username', 'name']

    objects = CustomerManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_admin

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True
```

**Login View:**

```
def loginUser(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('home')
        
    else:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            email = request.POST.get('email')
            password = request.POST.get('password')

            user = authenticate(request, email=email, password=password)

            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('home')
            else:
                messages.info(request, 'Email or Password didn\'t match!')

        context = {}
        return render(request, 'accounts/login.html', context)
```

**Logout View:**

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
def logoutUser(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect('login')
```

**User Profile View:**

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
def userProfile(request, email):
    customer = Customer.objects.filter(email=email).first()
    context = {'customer':customer}
    return render(request, 'accounts/profile.html', context)
```

**CreateUserForm and LoginForm:**

```
class CreateUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'name', 'password1', 'password2']
        # fields = '__all__'


class LoginForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(label='password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = ['email', 'password']
    
    def clean(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        password = self.cleaned_data['password']
        if not authenticate(email=email, password=password):
            raise forms.ValidationError('Incorrect Login')
```

**When User3 is logged in and admin is not logged in:**

[image]

**As soon as admin logged in:**
User3 automatically logs out and admin logs in..

[image]

Comment: Use a different browser or incognito mode?

Comment: Yes working, for different browser or incognito it is working. Thank You!